# Возврат данных процедуры с помощью выходных параметров

Tags: sql-server

Есть код он работает

```
SELECT category , brand FROM products
INNER JOIN categories c ON products.category_id = c.id
INNER JOIN  brands b ON products.brand_id = b.id
WHERE products.id = 12
```

Выдаёт, категорию и бренд товара

Запрос работает ,а процедура нет

делал так

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_product ( @product_id INT,
@brend_name VARCHAR(100) OUT, @category_name VARCHAR(100) OUT)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT @brend_name = brand, @category_name = category FROM products
INNER JOIN categories c ON products.category_id = c.id
INNER JOIN  brands b ON products.brand_id = b.id
WHERE id = @product_id

END
GO
```

Вызываю так

```
DECLARE
@product_id int,
@brend_name nvarchar(100),
@category_name nvarchar(100)


SET @product_id = 5;
EXECUTE get_product @product_id, @brend_name OUT, @category_name OUT;
SELECT @brend_name, @category_name
```

Вроде всё правельно но
не работает , что я делаю не так?

Выдаёт null и название столбцов anonimus

Comment: В процедуре вы должны задать значения двум out-параметрам, а вы их зачем-то используете в условии.

Comment: уберите out переменные из where и добавьте их в select `SELECT @brend_name= brand, @category_name=category`

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis  попробую! Спасибо!

Comment: @Alexander Petrov А, как задать то?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Не не работает. Выдаёт два поля <ananimus> со значением <null>

Comment: вызов должен выглядеть так - `DECLARE
@product_id int,
@brend_name_out nvarchar(100),
@category_name_out nvarchar(100)


SET @product_id = 5;
EXECUTE get_product @product_id, @brend_name=@brend_name_out OUTPUT, @category_name=@category_name_out OUTPUT;
SELECT @brend_name_out, @category_name_out`

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Спасибо работает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызов процедуры должен выглядеть так:

```
DECLARE @product_id int, 
@brend_name_out nvarchar(100), 
@category_name_out nvarchar(100) 
SET @product_id = 5; 
EXECUTE get_product @product_id, @brend_name=@brend_name_out OUTPUT, @category_name=@category_name_out OUTPUT; 
SELECT @brend_name_out, @category_name_out
```